# How can run rendering tests in gitlab cicd?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, pyglet, xvfb

I am trying to run some tests using pytest in Gitlab CI/CD. Some of those tests include rendering using the Pyglet module.

I get an error:

```
pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException: No standard config is available.
```

I have tried both `headless=True` and `False`.
Then I found `xvfb` so I tried to run the test by making a virtual screen:

```
  before_script:
    - apt-get install -y xorg-dev libglu1-mesa libgl1-mesa-dev xvfb libxinerama1 libxcursor1
    - export DISPLAY=:0
  script:
    - conda run -n myenv-3.10-cpu xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24 +extension RANDR" python -m pytest -vvv ./tests
```

This did not solve my issue since I got the same error.
Note that the tests run perfectly fine locally on my laptop.

Traceback:

```
    from pyglet.window import key
/root/miniconda3/envs/myenv-3.10-cpu/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py:1929: in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
/root/miniconda3/envs/myenv-3.10-cpu/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py:165: in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = ShadowWindow()
/root/miniconda3/envs/myenv-3.10-cpu/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py:159: in __init__
    super().__init__(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
```

This is an example test that will fail with the prementioned error:

```
def test_pyglet():
 import pyglet

 window = pyglet.window.Window()

 label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width // 2, y=window.height // 2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

 @window.event
 def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

 pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: ARe you able to run tests locally with `xvfb-run` without X server, ex. on ctrl+alt+F1, or without DISPLAY?

Comment: I can run the same command : conda run -n myenv-3.10-cpu xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24 +extension RANDR" python -m pytest -vvv ./tests without any problem. I run this on my terminal using the same conda environment myenv-3.10-cpu.

Comment: I think the possibility we want to rule out is that, locally, your tests are not actually using the virtual display. Instead of running `pytest` with your command, try running `python -m pyglet.info` both locally and when running in GitLab CI, which should provide more information about the differences in what is going on.

Comment: @sytech, nice idea. Actually, this command is throwing an error `pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context` .

Comment: Does it raise this error both locally and in CI? Or just in CI? Do you have OpenGL available on the systems?

Comment: this error is only in CI. Locally, everything is running as expected. I have no errors.  For the gitlab cicd I am not sure if OpenGL is available.

Comment: When I run $ glxinfo in CI I get Error: unable to open display

Answer (score 0):

ckeck this code snippet.

```
before_script:
  - apt-get install -y xorg-dev libglu1-mesa libgl1-mesa-dev xvfb libxinerama1 libxcursor1
  - export DISPLAY=:0
  - Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1400x900x24 +extension RANDR &

script:
  - conda run -n myenv-3.10-cpu python -m pytest -vvv ./tests
```

Comment: I just did, unfortunately I get the same error